# "ERROR missing ) after argument list" when running 'npm run dev'

Tags: npm, module, nuxt.js, node-modules, nuxt3

Description:
I'm facing a recurring issue with my Nuxt.js project. Whenever I run 'npm run dev' in the terminal, I encounter the following error:

```
ERROR missing ) after argument list                                                                                            

  at DefaultModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:116:18)
  at DefaultModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:190:14)
  at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:21)
```

The problem persists across both my old and new projects. I'm seeking assistance in understanding the cause of this error and how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried tracing the error but I can't.